# Post IDs inside cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to build a recently viewed WP widget using a cookie.

My code is as follows:

```
function complete_cookie() {    

        $data = get_the_ID();
        //$data = implode( ',' , get_the_ID() ); // not working
        setcookie( 'mp_last_viewed_cookie', json_encode( $data ), strtotime( '+30 days' ), COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false, false );
    }
    add_action( 'get_header', 'complete_cookie' );
```

Inside my widget I use the cookie like this:

```
if ( $sortby == 'recently_viewed' ) {
        if ( isset( $_COOKIE['mp_last_viewed_cookie'] ) ) {

            $items = json_decode( stripslashes( $_COOKIE['mp_last_viewed_cookie'] ), true );

            if ( ! empty( $items ) ) {              
                $params['post__in'] = array($items);
                $params['orderby'] = 'post__in';
                $params['post__not_in'] = array($post_id);
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
```

When I do `var_dump($items);` it only shows one post ID which is expected considering I use `$data = get_the_ID();`

I tried using `$data = implode( ',' , get_the_ID() );` but that didn't work. Anyone an idea on how to get a list of viewed post ID, rather than simply one? I'd like to show 4 latest viewed posts.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does it mean that each time `complete_cookie()` is called you want to add the current post ID to the list of recently viewed? And `get_the_ID()` returns just the last post viewed?

Comment: Yes, that's right. But it seems the cookie already does that. I updated my original post for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took some time, but I finally got it working.

```
function complete_cookie() {

    $viewed_posts = array();    

    if(isset($_COOKIE['mp_recently_viewed']) && $_COOKIE['mp_recently_viewed']!='') { 

        $viewed_posts =  unserialize($_COOKIE['mp_recently_viewed']);

        if (! is_array($viewed_posts)) {            
                $viewed_posts = array(get_the_ID()); 
        } else{          
         $viewed_posts = array_diff($viewed_posts, array(get_the_ID())); // for removing current post in cookie 
            array_unshift($viewed_posts,get_the_ID());// update cookie with current post
        }

     } else {
          $viewed_posts = array(get_the_ID());
     }

     setcookie( 'mp_recently_viewed', serialize($viewed_posts), strtotime( '+7 days' ), COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false, false );

}
add_action( 'get_header', 'complete_cookie' );
```

And inside the widget I used this:

```
$params = array(
        'post_type'      => 'download',
        'posts_per_page' => $limit,
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'offset'         => $offset,
     );

if ( $sortby == 'recently_viewed' ) {
        if(isset($_COOKIE['mp_recently_viewed']) && $_COOKIE['mp_recently_viewed']!='') {

            $viewed_posts =  unserialize($_COOKIE['mp_recently_viewed']);

            if ( ! empty( $viewed_posts ) ) {               
                $params['post__in'] = $viewed_posts;
                $params['orderby'] = 'post__in';
                $params['post__not_in'] = array( get_the_ID() );
            }
        } else {

        }
    }

$post_query = new WP_Query($params);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first element in your json is an array, then [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) will return an array.
You don't need to create another array, you just need to assign the return value to you variable.

```
$params['post__in'] = $items;
```

### Edit after last comment

To append your new ID to the existing one

```
if ( isset( $_COOKIE['mp_last_viewed_cookie'] ) ) {
    $data = json_decode( stripslashes( $_COOKIE['mp_last_viewed_cookie'] ), true );
    $data[] = get_the_ID();

} else {
    $data = array(get_the_ID());
}

setcookie( 'mp_last_viewed_cookie', json_encode( $data ), strtotime( '+30 days' ), COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false, false );
```

Comment: When I do that, I get the following error: `WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'edd_price' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value ' at line 1]`

Comment: I was wrong. :( My cookie only stores one post ID. The var_dump I used was from a different cookie. So I'm back to square one. Apologies.

Comment: For some odd reasons, it doesn't work. When I do var_dump($data); it only shows `int(8384)` This number stays the same even if I visit other pages with different post IDs.